# Sudo Port command is failing on Sierra

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sierra, macports

I have been trying to install macports but I am just not able to get through this step : `sudo port`

I have done the basic checks:

- Install the latest xcode and the xcode developer tools.This is what I get when I do `gcc -v` :
  `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
  Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`
- Changing the Path :`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
- And finally rebooting the terminal.

Not sure what is wrong. Also somehow I am getting the `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:` twice in my PATH. I have tried undoing all the PATH variable changes, I made so far (courtesy Google). 
Here is my env :

```
MANPATH=/opt/local/man:
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/4z/mtr7vn854t79rv33nrxr74000080ns/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Pskf5fuPHk/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=388.1
TERM_SESSION_ID=A3892840-4956-4457-9821-ECF6037BBCC7
USER=rekhag
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Tfg3TZVrnw/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x402B9:0x0:0x0
SK_SIGNING_PLUGIN=gnubbyagent
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD=/Users/rekhag
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/rekhag
LOGNAME=rekhag
_=/usr/bin/env
```

`

Any clue what is happening here ?

Comment: What you haven't shown is the exact `sudo port ...` command you're issuing and the resulting output (e.g. error message).

Comment: @KenThomases : Just this 
`sudo port`
`sudo: port: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

The 'port' command takes various verbs.  Documentation on basic usage is at:

https://guide.macports.org/#using

As that page says, the very first command you need to run is:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

Assuming that works, you can then find the software you want to install (say "foo") with:

```
port search foo
```

Get information about a particular package with:

```
port info foo
```

Then, if foo is what you really want, install it with:

```
sudo port install foo
```

Craig

(Just running 'sudo port' by itself puts you in "shell" mode.  That's an uncommon way to use MacPorts; at least nowadays.)

Comment: Even the `sudo port selfupdate` gives me `sudo: port: command not found`.

Comment: Almost certainly just a PATH problem.  To verify that 'port' works, use the full path:  `sudo /opt/local/bin/port selfupdate`

Comment: Thank you it worked. I know I have messed up the PATH, just started with UNIX. I tried reverting all the changes but looks like I am still not able to  get it right. Any reference on how can I fix it ? 
Appreciate your help :)